# Pull on refresh without pulling animation in ListView

Tags: flutter

I have used ListView inside RefreshIndicator and also SmartRefresher but the thing is when i pull down it animates the pulling. I dont want to show the pulling animation. I have tried clampingscrollphysics to disable pulling animation but if I use it, refresh will not work. So please let me know how can I make a pull to refresh that will show refresh indicator and also will refresh but will not show the pull down animation with list view

Answer (score 0):

Apply custom physics class into your listview.

```
  ListView.builder(
          physics: Custom2ScrollPhysics()
  )
```

Custom2ScrollPhysics classs

```
    class Custom2ScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
      /// Creates scroll physics that prevent the scroll offset from exceeding the
      /// bounds of the content..
      const Custom2ScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics parent}) : super(parent: parent);

      @override
      Custom2ScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
        return Custom2ScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));
      }

      @override
      double applyBoundaryConditions(ScrollMetrics position, double value) {
        assert(() {
          if (value == position.pixels) {
            throw FlutterError('$runtimeType.applyBoundaryConditions() was called redundantly.\n'
                'The proposed new position, $value, is exactly equal to the current position of the '
                'given ${position.runtimeType}, ${position.pixels}.\n'
                'The applyBoundaryConditions method should only be called when the value is '
                'going to actually change the pixels, otherwise it is redundant.\n'
                'The physics object in question was:\n'
                '  $this\n'
                'The position object in question was:\n'
                '  $position\n');
          }
          return true;
        }());
        if (value < position.pixels && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) // underscroll
          return value - position.pixels;
        if (position.maxScrollExtent <= position.pixels && position.pixels < value) // overscroll
          return value - position.pixels;
        if (value < position.minScrollExtent && position.minScrollExtent < position.pixels) // hit top edge
          return value - position.minScrollExtent;
        if (position.pixels < position.maxScrollExtent && position.maxScrollExtent < value) // hit bottom edge
          return value - position.maxScrollExtent;
        return 0.0;
      }

      @override
      Simulation createBallisticSimulation(ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
        final Tolerance tolerance = this.tolerance;
        if (position.outOfRange) {
          double end;
          if (position.pixels > position.maxScrollExtent) end = position.maxScrollExtent;
          if (position.pixels < position.minScrollExtent) end = position.minScrollExtent;
          assert(end != null);
          return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, position.pixels, end, min(0.0, velocity), tolerance: tolerance);
        }
        if (velocity.abs() < tolerance.velocity) return null;
        if (velocity > 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent) return null;
        if (velocity < 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) return null;
        return ClampingScrollSimulation(
          position: position.pixels,
          velocity: velocity,
          tolerance: tolerance,
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not working. Maybe I am doing it in a wrong way ! Can you please give me the source code of above example gif?